# How can I scale the HTML5 canvas without making it blurry?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have created a canvas using the following markup:

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Now, if I specify `width` and `height` here directly, then the drawings on canvas will be pretty sharp.

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="600px" height="400px"></canvas>
```

but this way I can't scale the canvas flexibly to cover every screen size. Using `vh` or `vw` instead of pixels doesn't work either. I tried setting them in JavaScript like:

```
$('#canvas').css({
   "height": window.innerHeight,
   "width": window.innerWidth
 });
```

this covered the whole canvas but made the lines blurry. Is there some way I can get sharp images while the canvas still covers whole screen?

I tried using:

```
$("#canvas")
.prop("width", window.innerWidth)
.prop("height", window.innerHeight);
```

but the objects on the canvas (for example a circle that I drew) are still blurry. When I open up devTools, I see the following markup:

```
<canvas id="canvas" style="height: 768px; width: 1366px;"></canvas>
```

So, I guess width and height are still being defined by CSS.

Comment: @Kaiido I have updated my question. I tried the solutions you linked to but I still get blurry figures.

Comment: If you resize the canvas with CSS you must keep the resulting canvas size in the same aspect ratio as the canvas element's original size. Otherwise you will get distortion (blurring, stretching, squishing, etc). Maintaining aspect ratio means you might not be able to cover every pixel of the window area because the window probably won't have the same aspect ratio as your original canvas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Canvas CSS properties do not resize canvas, they rescale it.
You may simply change the properties with your JS:

```
$("#canvas")
    .prop("width", window.innerWidth)
    .prop("height", window.innerHeight);
```

Comment: You must warn that resizing the canvas element will also *automatically clear the canvas contents so everything must be redrawn*.

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
```

Comment: Did you remove your snippet?

Comment: You must warn that resizing the canvas element will also automatically clear the canvas contents so everything must be redrawn

Answer (score 2):

1. `canvas` element size is controlled by its attributes `width` and `height`. To change the size you need to modify these attributes, not CSS. And they don't need units, they are in pixels.

   ```
   <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
   ```
2. Canvas draws bitmap, it's not scalable like vectors. You could only redraw the canvas after resized.

Comment: Your (2) is a common misconception. :-) Canvas calculates in vectors (just like SVG) and it displays as a quasi-bitmap (just like SVG). The difference is that SVG "remembers" what it drew so it can automatically rescale its drawings. Canvas  doesn't "remember" what it drew so it can't automatically rescale it's drawings. Resizing the canvas element automatically erases all drawings, so you must redraw the drawings. Canvas's "vector" calculations let you rescale your re-drawings with one simple command: `context.scale`. ;-)

Comment: @markE I didn't know the `context.scale ` thing. Looks like I should revisit some learning materials :)